# Where is POST method saved in express?

Tags: node.js, express, httprequest, backend, body-parser

So I'm new to Backend and is learning about HTTP request. As far as I know GET is for getting a resource from backend and displays it on the browser. Then there is POST to post a resource, but where does it posted? I'm using express as framework. This is my code:

```
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.post('/name', (req, res) => {
  let first = req.body.first;
  let last = req.body.last;
  res.json({
    'name': `${first} ${last}`
  })
})

module.exports = app;
```

**I successfully displayed the respond** (a JSON with properties `name: ${first} ${last}`) **after I submitted the form**. But where does this JSON is saved? How can I access the JSON again?

Do I still need to push it to database to have access to submitted JSON? Because I thought before, POST will POST the submitted value.

Any helpful answer would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to collect and cache the POST data yourself if you want it to be accessible later on, once you refresh the page or post another form, the previously posted data will no longer exist.

Comment: It is not saved. It is stored in the variables `first` and `last`. It is up to you to save it, you can use an sql server, you can use mongodb etc. All that saving stuff is completely separate from express.

Answer (score 0):

`res.json` is similar to sending response data back to the client side. At the client side, you can use a variable to store the result of calling this http request and then you can use the data it sends back.